# Filtering listview using cursorAdapter error

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

Im having a problem about filtering my listView. Whenever Im trying to input a text in my editText, nothing changed.

Maybe the problem is about this.. my mCursor declaration

```
Cursor mCursor = myDatabaseHelper.getDirectoryList(null);
```

I tried to change the parameter from null to "Android", the output shows the term Android in my listView.. but if the parameter is set to null, then every term in my dictionary is displayed in the listView.

I have another code fragment in the same class that calls the getDirectoryList but it seems that the parameter in that fragment is ignored. Please help me..

Here is the code

```
 public class SearchActivity extends Activity{

private DatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper;

  /* Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);

      myDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
      try {
        myDatabaseHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      myDatabaseHelper.openDataBase();


      Cursor mCursor = myDatabaseHelper.getDirectoryList(null);


      String[] from = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.KEY_CONTENT};
      int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
      SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mCursor, from, to);
        startManagingCursor(mCursor);

        ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

      listContent.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
      listContent.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      EditText etext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      etext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          }

          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
          }

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
              SimpleCursorAdapter filterAdapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter)listContent.getAdapter();
              filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
              //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });

      myDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
     cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
          public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
              //myDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
              //int x = constraint.toString().length();
              myDatabaseHelper.getDirectoryList(constraint);
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), constraint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              return myDatabaseHelper.getDirectoryList(constraint);

          }
        });


      myDatabaseHelper.close();
```

and my getDirectory class

```
 public Cursor getDirectoryList (CharSequence constraint)  {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(DB_NAME);

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_NETWORKING, KEY_HARDWARE, KEY_SOFTWARE, KEY_INTERNET, KEY_TECHNOLOGY};


    if (constraint == null  ||  constraint.length () == 0)  {
        //  Return the full list
        //String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_NETWORKING, KEY_HARDWARE, KEY_SOFTWARE, KEY_INTERNET, KEY_TECHNOLOGY};Toast.makeText(getContext(), constraint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query("MY_TABLE", 
                 columns, KEY_TECHNOLOGY + "='Y'", null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }  else  {
            String value = constraint.toString()+"%";
            Cursor cursor2 = myDataBase.query("MY_TABLE", columns, KEY_CONTENT + " like ?", new String[]{value}, null, null, null);
            return cursor2;
        }
    }

}
```